# How to optimize the performance of a stored procedure in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, stored-procedures

I am using PostgreSQL 10.9 on Ubuntu 18.04.1. The follwing stored procedure does take an array as input and a variable beta. Both input variables are used to compute an aggregated index. The array can have a varying length. 
As I am using this function several thousands times inside another query, the performance of this function is very important. I removed a CTE and changed it to a subquery, this helped a bit. However I couldn't find any other way to improve performance further.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.part_accessibility_index(traveltime_array NUMERIC[], beta numeric)
RETURNS SETOF NUMERIC 

LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$

    SELECT COALESCE(sum_index,0) 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT sum(part) sum_index
        FROM ( 
            SELECT EXP(UNNEST(traveltime_array)*(beta)) AS part
        )
        index_part 
    )
    sum_index;

$function$
```

The function can be called likes this

```
SELECT part_accessibility_index(ARRAY[100.2,323.9,1323.313,432.232,1100.22,144.1], -0.001)
```

I get the following query plan.

```
ProjectSet  (cost=0.00..5.27 rows=1000 width=32) (actual time=0.180..0.184 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.000..0.001 rows=1 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.022 ms
Execution time: 0.197 ms
```

As mentioned the query is not really slow but probably there are still ways in improving it. I would be very happy for any help!

Answer (score 5):

There are a few things you could try, which might help performance:

1. Re-write the function in C.  This is obviously the most effort, but it could be the biggest payoff if you really need the performance.
2. You can remove one sub-query by moving the coalesce down to `coalesce(sum(part), 0)`.  In fact, I don't think you need any sub-queries:

```
  SELECT coalesce(sum(exp(part*beta)), 0) sum_index
        FROM UNNEST(traveltime_array) AS u(part)
```

3. Your function doesn't return a set.  Change it to just return numeric.
4. Try changing it to a plpgsql function.  The query plan may be cached after the fifth execution per session if the plan is not significantly worse than the generic plan.
5. As the function does not modify the database or use session info, it can safely be marked as immutable, which may help the optimizer choose a better plan.
6. Likewise, the function can be marked as parallel safe, which will allow parallel workers to call the function.  This could help if the calling query can be parallelized.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Jeremy! I followed most of your recommendations. Besides rewriting the function ;)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.part_accessibility_index(traveltime_array NUMERIC[], beta numeric)
RETURNS NUMERIC 
AS $function$
DECLARE 
    sum_index NUMERIC;
BEGIN 
    SELECT COALESCE(sum(part),0) INTO sum_index
    FROM ( 
        SELECT EXP(UNNEST(traveltime_array)*(beta)) AS part
    )
    index_part; 
    RETURN sum_index; 
END;
$function$ LANGUAGE plpgsql immutable;
```

Especially adding the keyword immutable made the execution time much faster. Though the planning time is now significantly longer. I could not find any solution for this.

```
Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=1 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.126 ms
Execution time: 0.004 ms
```