# PostgreSQL Procedure Performance

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-16

I am running in little performance issue in PostgreSQL (V16) and calls between procedures. If I take only this code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE perf_test_3() AS
$body$
DECLARE
begin
end;
$body$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE perf_test_2() AS
$body$
DECLARE
begin
  CALL perf_test_3();
end;
$body$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE perf_test_1() AS
$body$
DECLARE
begin
  CALL perf_test_2();
end;
$body$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

do $$ 
DECLARE 
    v_ii int;
    v_start            timestamp(3);
    v_end              timestamp(3);
BEGIN
    v_start := clock_timestamp();
    for v_ii in 1..500000 LOOP
        call perf_test_1();
    END LOOP;
    v_end := clock_timestamp();
    RAISE NOTICE 'start time %', v_start;
    RAISE NOTICE 'end   time %', v_end;
    RAISE NOTICE 'run   time %', v_end-v_start;
END; 
$$;
```

This loop took about 2sec doing "nothing"

```
NOTICE:  start time 2024-02-20 16:37:15.76
NOTICE:  end   time 2024-02-20 16:37:17.547
NOTICE:  run   time 00:00:01.787
```

If I have tons of records and multiple different procedures for calculations, the total run is compared to Oracle PL/SQL much too high (4min in Oracle, 1h in PostgreSQL). It is not the processing within each of the procedures, those are fast (statement, calculations, etc.), it is more the call between of the procedures, which makes it slow.

Based on the post [Hot to optimize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57342383/how-to-optimize-the-performance-of-a-stored-procedure-in-postgres), with functions goes better (save 1sec), but from my perspective even to high. Is there any other option/information, how to optimize the pl/sql engine.

Comment: `(4min in Oracle, 1h in PostgreSQL)` that difference can't be explained by the code above. Something to avoid in programming, is a loop. Check pg_stat_user_functions to see what function/procedure takes most of the time and start with that one to optimize.

Comment: Your demonstration doesn't demonstrate your conclusion.  How do you get from 1.8 seconds to an hour? What does the equivalent demonstration in Oracle show?

Comment: Changing the code to functions: `completed in 327 ms`

Comment: I would not be surprised if this has something to do with parallelization. Oracle is highly optimized for that, PostgreSQL procedures don't even have this option yet. You have to use functions and configure the function to be parallel safe.

Comment: Use procedures only when you want to work with transactions - use explicit commit, explicit rollback. Without it, use functions. There is not any benefit from procedures, and execution of functions is better optimized.

Comment: PL/pgSQL is interpreted language inside SQL engine. PL/SQL is fully compiled language outside SQL engine. The overhead of PL/pgSQL for empty load should be significantly higher. There is not any possibility to reduce it. PL/pgSQL should be used as glue for SQL - and then the overhead of PL/SQL against SQL queries is +/- zero.

Comment: @FrankHeikens, we have tons of base function, where simple “if” stmt or even the same identical calculation are development. In C you would do a macro or an inline function. So I have one function, which gets the information, collects from 5 other functions data, which uses itself 5 other ones….. and finally stores multiple records. this sums up.

Comment: As an example, I have a cache routine, 500.000 time called took 1-2sec., let’s say it is the perf_3, the perf_2 as only a check, if the cached record can be used, a simple if stmt, I have additional 5 seconds, and so on..

Comment: Sounds like what we do. We have about 10 functions (not procedures) that are used somewhere between 40 and 200 million times a day. These 10 functions use in total about 1100 functions written in SQL and PLpgSQL and must respond within a few milliseconds. Database is about 10TB in size and most of the data is actively used in these functions. To me it's not clear what your problem is, hard to help.